# Using arrays and hitTest - AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

From what my friend has told me, this should be working but it is not.

```
var P2hb:Array = new Array(P2char1, P2char2, P2char3);
var P2life:Number = 0;  

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, framecheck)
function framecheck(event:Event):void
{
if (P2hb.hitTestObject(P1attack)) { P2life-=2; }
}
```

This is a generic code but it is the same as what I have. Basically,
all elements in the `P2hb` are *movieclips* on the stage.
I want to say that, if `P1attack` hits any of the objects in the array, then `P2life` will drop by 2, without having to type `hitTestObject()` for each individual object.
I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `P2hb` is an `Array` in which there is no `hitTestObject()` method! You most probably meant something like: `P2hb[0].hitTestObject(P1attack)` for the `if` statement criteria!

Comment: ... and, what do you want to do?!

Comment: how do I get [0] to equal all three objects?

Comment: I want to say that if P1attack hits any of the objects in the array then P2life will drop by 2, without having to type hitTestObject for each individual object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, loop through each individual "movieClip" in the array (using a [`for`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html) loop, for example) and check for the collision against your other object:

```
function framecheck(event:Event):void
{
    for each (var enemy in P2hb) {
        if (enemy.hitTestObject(P1attack)) {
            P2life-=2;
            trace("hit occurred! P2life: "+P2life);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will this check all movieclips in the same frame? or check each movie clip frame by frame? would like to have it check all clips in a single frame

Comment: I tried the code and it only triggers on the second item in the array

Comment: @Koden Since, you've registered the `framecheck()` function as the `ENTER_FRAME` handler, then _all_ the code inside the function will be carried out _once_ while the "play head" enters _each frame_ :)

Comment: @Koden _[It](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858562/using-arrays-and-hittest-as3#comment68934999_40859540)_ indicates that your `P1attack` only hits with the _second item_, though!